# SQL Server: calculate working time

Tags: sql-server, function

How I can calculate the working time in SQL Server between two `datetime` variables, excluding the holidays?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holidays aren't universal - they depends **very much** on your location. Not even the fact which days of the week are "working" days is the same - it depends on your location.

Because of that, a general, universal answer will not be possible, and for that reason, there's also no system-provided function in T-SQL for doing this. How would SQL Server know what holidays you have in your corner of the world??.

You need to have a table of your holidays somewhere in your system and handle it yourself.

Some posts that might be of some help to you:

- [Calculate Number of Working Days in SQL Server](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/05/calculate-number-of-working-days-in-sql.html): this just basically removes any Saturdays and Sundays - but doesn't include other holidays
- [How do I count the number of business days between two dates?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/date-time-routines-manipulation/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates.html) : shows the same main approach, with the addition of a table that contains other holidays like Easter, 4th of July (US National Holiday) and so on

Answer (score 2):

Like marc_s says, you currently need a custom solution.  I really hope Microsoft adds some standard functionality: it's tough to get right, and holidays are pretty much standardized by location.

Here's an example:

```
declare @start_date datetime
declare @end_date datetime
set @start_date = '2010-12-20'
set @end_date = '2010-12-26'

-- A table with all non-working days.  This just adds Christmass, but you
-- probably should add weekends as well.
declare @non_working_days table (dt datetime)
insert @non_working_days values ('2010-12-25'), ('2010-12-26')

-- Remove the time part
set @start_date = DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, @start_date))
set @end_date = DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, @end_date))

-- Find the number of non-working-days
declare @nwd_count int
select  @nwd_count = count(*) 
from    @non_working_days 
where   dt >= @start_date and dt < @end_date

-- Print result
select datediff(DAY, @start_date, @end_date) - @nwd_count
```

This prints 5, because the 25th is not a working day.

Comment: Actually: location alone won't do. Here in Switzerland, each canton (= State) has their own public holidays which often go beyond the national holidays - plus the Catholic cantons have a lot more Christian holidays than the others.. and that's just for one tiny country in the middle of Europe... it's really quite messy (and quite dependant on so many factors, any "globally valid" approach is doomed to fail)

Comment: @marc_s: Yeah, it wouldn't be perfect.  I can just imagine the Islamic Butcher Association having entirely different rules from the Kosher Meat Producers.  Still, a default setup would help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a table which has a row for every date you're interested in, and, say, a "working hours" column, or just a "working day" indicator if you want to do it at day granularity. (I find this approach makes the final SQL simpler, plus enables all sorts of other useful queries, but then I'm into data warehousing, rather than operational databases, so you may find the "just list the holidays" approach better, depending...)

You will, of course, have to create that table yourself, working from some feed of holiday dates for the region you're interested in.

Typically you can project these forward at least a year, as most public holidays are agreed a long way in advance (though there are some that pop up at the "last minute" -- in the UK, for example, 29 April will be an extra public holiday in 2010, as there's a royal wedding taking place, and we got less than a year's notice of that.

Then you just

```
SELECT
   SUM(working_hours)
FROM 
   all_dates 
WHERE
   the_date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
```

If you want to do this internationally, it gets incredibly difficult to get your data; there's no sensible source that I know of for international holiday dates, and different regions in a "country" might have different dates -- e.g. you may know that someone's in the United Kingdom, but unless you know if they're in Scotland or not, you won't know if the first two days of the year are a public holiday, or just the first...